# R read pdf file and convert it to a byte array to store in sql server

Tags: r, binary, rodbc, varbinary, varbinarymax

Using R, I would like to take pdf files and store them into a sql server varbinary(max) field as a byte array. I'll use rodbc to insert the data. I'm stuck with how to read the file in and get it converted into a byte array before passing it to rodbc. What functions should I be looking at?

Comment: Are you trying to completely scrape PDFs, or grab tables out of them? If you're trying to extract tables, I have had good success with the `tabulizer` package.

Comment: If you're trying to just scrape the full contents of each document, you might try `pdftools`

Comment: not trying to scrape, I need to load them into sql server so that a website can access them.  I tried the method in the link below but i get an error 'Calloc' could not allocate memory (2147483648 of 1 bytes) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39270364/inserting-into-sql-server-varbinary-column-from-r-script

Answer (score 0):

There is probably more that one way to skin this cat, but I have done this in the past.

```
myPdf <- file("test.pdf", "rb")
myBinVec <- readBin(myPdf, raw(), n=1000000) #N needs to be larger than your file.
myBase64 <- rawToBase64(myBinVec)
```

Then insert the base64 into SQL server and use X-Query to convert to the base64 to a varbinary as illustrated here: https://blog.falafel.com/t-sql-easy-base64-encoding-and-decoding/

This is the reverse of a process we use to read pdfs (and similar to a process we have used to insert them although they come to us base64 encoded already). I would note you may be able to insert the `?raw()` binary directly into SQL or convert it in R to varbinary, however I have never tested this.